# Prevent Laravel from handling public folder as route

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am trying to utilize a custom made library (which is not created in Laravel) in a Laravel project.

The library calls ajax files and Laravel is trying to handle them via routing resulting in routing errors.

Is there a way to prevent Laravel from treating the library's files as routes?

Comment: Add regex to your routes.php file to bypass the libraries...see here for many different methods https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing

Comment: Any chance you can be a bit more specific? How do I make them bypass my library? My library is in public/libraries/generator3 and I would like to allow any HTTP requests to anything inside this folder to circumvent the larvel routing.

Comment: what kind of library? Javascript or Php?

Comment: It is custom made. It is mainly javascript but utilizes ajax calls to certain php files. It is basically a tool for creating ads online and convert them to pdfs.